# Will we regularly record statistics for our site?

Tags: discussion, statistics

There are some statistics on Worldbuilding.SE on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63276/worldbuilding). Some other sites have a community wiki topic where the statistics are recorded every week or every other week. Do we want to make something like this?

The statistics for the first few days are misleading, so starting this before day 7 doesn't seem to be a good idea, but at least we have time to discuss it how to do it (if we want to).

For full disclosure: I can't volunteer to become WB.SE's record keeper if the community wants to establish this function.

Comment: To the downvoters: We're very young, fresh SE community. Can we start professionally? Can we avoid stupid and annoing downvotes without expressing any reason for downvote in a comment? This is hard to be forced by configuration. Can we at least try to be professionals?

Comment: @trejder **Voting works differently on meta sites.** On meta sites, voting is normally used to indicate dis-/agreement with the point made. So the fact that this post has received two downvotes means that two users disagree with doing what it proposes or feel that doing what it proposes is unnecessary, nothing more. Also remember that voting doesn't award (or cost) reputation on meta sites, so there is no downside (or benefit) to voting either way for anyone involved (the only exception to this latter is [meta.se]).

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @trejder You're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Once we have established at least [*pro tempore* moderators](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35/29), this becomes much less necessary. While analytics data is intended only for moderators, and as such cannot be shared in detail with the community at large, **moderators do have access specifically to such statistics** as number of page views, visitors, posts, referrer statistics, new user counts, etc. which provide insight into one aspect of the health of a site. Such statistics go back to the birth of the site.

In the absence of any moderators, Stack Exchange staff has access to this data and **are likely monitoring it already.**